# Regular expression in Powershell to exclude all new lines starting with text

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file like:

```
    CF1 mytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytext
    CF2 mytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmy
    CF3 mytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytext
    CF4 mytextmytextmytextmextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmyt
    mytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytext
    CF5 mytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytext
```

I need to remove the new line from the CF4 row.

I am trying this code but it is not removing that line break:

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText( "MyFile.txt" ) 
$content = $content -replace "(`n|`r)?!CF", "CF"    Write-Host $content
```

Comment: Try `$content -replace '(?m)\r?\n(?!\s*CF)'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(Get-Content $filepath -Raw) -replace "(?>\r\n?|\n)(?!CF)", "" > $filepathout
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3E%5Cr%5Cn%3F%7C%5Cn%29%28%3F!CF%29&i=CF1%20mytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytext%0D%0ACF2%20mytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmy%0D%0ACF3%20mytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytext%0D%0ACF4%20mytextmytextmytextmextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmyt%0D%0Amytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytext%0D%0ACF5%20mytextmytextmytextmytextmytextmytext&r=). Details:

- `(?>\r\n?|\n)` - a CRLF, LF or CR line ending sequence
- `(?!CF)`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `CF` substring immediately to the right of the current location.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]